# Python wired CPU usage in windows task manager

Tags: python, windows, cpu-usage, taskmanager

I'm working on a Python project that analyzes audio and visualizes it to synchronize with club lights. To optimize performance, the application spawns multiple processes; for instance, one process handles the audio analysis (which is computationally intensive) while another manages the visualization.

When observing Task Manager, I've noticed an inconsistency. The overall CPU usage displayed is quite high around 70%, yet when I switch to the details tab, it shows the usage for my process at around only 20%. Which makes more sense because it's just one process running on a single core.

Why is there this diffrence in CPU usage display between the main Task Manager view and the details view?

Process view with high usage:

[image]

Detailed view with also 80% idle process

[image]